# How similar/dissimilar are the requirements to be a registered nurse in America and Europe?

Tags: health-education, different-national-health, hospital, medical-training

How different are the college programs? Is nursing school more difficult in Europe or America? What is the average time a person spends on college to become a registered nurse in Europe?